# Validating External Database Dataset with PySpark and Performing RDD Validation in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have recently been exploring Apache Spark, and my understanding is that it is a powerful tool for processing big data. One of its key features is the ability to store data across clusters.

Spark enables parallel processing of big data, which can be categorized into four types:

1. Volume: Deals with large amounts of data.
2. Velocity: Handles data generated at high speeds, such as real-time
   or streaming data.
3. Variety: Supports different types and formats of data, including
   structured, unstructured, and semi-structured data.
4. Veracity: Addresses the accuracy and reliability of data.

Now, I have a specific scenario where I need to migrate my existing ETL script from Node.js to PySpark. Currently, my ETL script in Node.js exposes an API that continuously receives data. Considering this, the data type I'm dealing with can be classified as "Velocity."

Here are my questions regarding the migration to PySpark:

1. Can I validate the request payload against a dataset stored in an
   external database using PySpark? I am concerned because PySpark
   stores data in a distributed manner across the cluster, and I want
   the validation to happen across all the data stored in the cluster.
2. Is it possible to validate two different RDDs in PySpark?

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on these matters.